# Mapreduce... doing a udacity course

Tags: mapreduce

as part of an udacity course I should program a mapper and a reducer function .
My mapper function looks like this.. and I am pretty sure it is working and right:

```
def mapper():
for line in sys.stdin:
    data= line.strip().split(",")
    #logging.info("{0}\t{1}".format(data[1],data[6]))
    print "{0}\t{1}".format(data[1],data[6])
```

mapper()

My reducer function somehow does not add it up correctly:

```
def reducer():
old_key=None
for line in sys.stdin:
    data= line.strip().split("\t")
    #logging.info(data)
 `   new_key=data[0] 
    ENTRIESn_hourly=data[1]
    count=0
    if new_key and new_key != ENTRIESn_hourly:
         print "{0}\t{1}".format(new_key,count)
    else:
         count+= int(ENTRIESn_hourly)
```

reducer()

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the count to zero every single input line. `count=0` should only be called when you have a new key, something like:

```
def reducer():
old_key=None
for line in sys.stdin:
    data= line.strip().split("\t")
    #logging.info(data)
 `   new_key=data[0] 
    ENTRIESn_hourly=data[1]
    if new_key and new_key != ENTRIESn_hourly:
         print "{0}\t{1}".format(new_key,count)
         count=0
    else:
         count+= int(ENTRIESn_hourly)
```